# How do I get low level data from the Flag module?

Tags: 8, flags

Is it possible to get the following raw, low level data from the Flag Module and/or it's services?

- Flagging count as integer
- URL to flag/unflag as a string
- Current user's flagging status as boolean

I already know that I can do this:

```
$flag_link = \Drupal::service('flag.link_builder')->build('node',$nid,'bookmark');
```

But it will output the full blown markup with Ajax and everything.

I've done this:

```
$flag_service = Drupal::service('flag.count');
$counts = $flag_service->getEntityFlagCounts($node);
```

But I can't actually figure out what exactly `$counts` contains, I definitely can't output it as an integer on my template, I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the total flagging count:

```
$count_service = \Drupal::service('flag.count');
$flag_counts = $count_service->getEntityFlagCounts($node);
$count = $flag_counts['my_flag'];
```

To get the current user's flagging status:

```
$flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
$my_flag = $flag_service->getFlagById('my_flag');
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();
$is_flagged= $my_flag->isFlagged($node,$user);
```

to toggle the flagging status:

```
if(!$is_flagged){
    $flag_service->flag($my_flag , $node);
}
```

or

```
if($is_flagged){
    $flag_service->unflag($my_flag , $node);
}
```

Best to wrap all of this into an if clause

```
if( $user->isAuthenticated() ){ ... }
```

It's probably easiest to just build my own URL / route to take care of the toggling to fit my needs.